# In pytorch, is there a built-in method to extract rows with given indexes?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a torch tensor

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9]])
```

and a list

```
b = [0,2]
```

Is there a built-in method to extract the rows 0 and 2 and put them in a new tensor:

```
tensor([[1,2,3],
        [7,8,9]])
```

In particular, is there a function that look likes this:

```
extract_rows(a,b) -> c
```

where `c` contains desired rows. Sure, this can done by a for loop, but a built-in method is in general faster.

Note that the example is only an example, there could be dozens of indexes in the list, and hundreds of rows in the tensor.

Comment: why this can done by a for loop? you can do this using slicing

Comment: @Sheri `for` loop solution: Build a new tensor of suitiable size, for each index in the list, copy that row from the old tensor to the corresponding row of the new tensor.

Comment: @Sheri How can this by done by slicing?

Comment: @Sheri What if the tensor has hundres of rows and there are dozens of indexes in the list?

Comment: Do you only want to extract the rows 0 and 2?

Comment: @Sheri No, the example is meant to be simple to help explain the outcome. The list could contain arbitrary row indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at torch builtin [index_select()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) method. It would be helpful to you.
or
You can do this using slicing.

```
tensor = [[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]]

new_tensor = tensor[0::2]
print(new_tensor)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `a[b]` would work

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9]])
b = [0,2]
a[b]
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [7, 8, 9]])
```